# React function only accept last item from UseEffect loop

Tags: reactjs, for-loop, react-hooks, fetch

I am new to react, i fetch data from server in an array and i want to create html elements for each element in an array, i can already create single element so i thought i can call the same function from a loop and pass the same required data and the item will be created, but the problem is that the last item only is being created , anyone know what iam doing wrong?
`import React, { useState , useEffect,useLayoutEffect} from "react";
import { Todo } from "./Todo";
import { TodoForm } from "./TodoForm";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import { EditTodoForm } from "./EditTodoForm";

```
uuidv4();
var i=0
export const TodoWrapper = () => {
  const [todos, setTodos] = useState([]);

  const addTodo = (todo,desc,time_value,img_value) => {
    setTodos([
      ...todos,
      { id: uuidv4(), task: todo,desc,time_value,img_value, completed: false, isEditing: false },
    ]);
    console.log(todos)
  }
  const deleteTodo = (id) => setTodos(todos.filter((todo) => todo.id !== id));

  const toggleComplete = (id) => {
    setTodos(
      todos.map((todo) =>
        todo.id === id ? { ...todo, completed: !todo.completed } : todo
      )
    );
  }

  const editTodo = (id) => {
    setTodos(
      todos.map((todo) =>
        todo.id === id ? { ...todo, isEditing: !todo.isEditing } : todo
      )
    );
  }

  const editTask = (task, id) => {
    setTodos(
      todos.map((todo) =>
        todo.id === id ? { ...todo, task, isEditing: !todo.isEditing } : todo
      )
    );
  };
  var x=[];
  const [data,setdata]=useState([{}])
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch(`http://localhost:5000/graphql-api`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      query: `{
        allTodos {
          edges {
            node {
              title,
              description,
              time,
              img,
          
            }
          }
        }
      }`,
    }),
  }).then(
      res => res.json()
    ).then(data => {setdata(data)
      console.log('i fire once');
    console.log(data.data.allTodos.edges.length)
    for(var i = 0; i < data.data.allTodos.edges.length; i++)
    {
        var product = data.data.allTodos.edges[i];
        console.log(product.node.title)
        addTodo(product.node.title,product.node.description,product.node.time,product.node.img)
        x.push([product.node.title,product.node.description,product.node.time,product.node.img])

      }
  console.log(x[0][0])

    }
  
    )

  
  }, []);


  return (
    <div className="TodoWrapper">
      <h1>Get Things Done !</h1>
      <TodoForm addTodo={addTodo} />
      {/* display todos */}
      {todos.map((todo,desc,time_value,img_value) =>
        todo.isEditing ? (
          <EditTodoForm editTodo={editTask} task={todo} />
        ) : (
          <Todo
            key={todo.id}
            task={todo}
            deleteTodo={deleteTodo}
            editTodo={editTodo}
            desc={desc}
            time={time_value}
            img_value={img_value}
            toggleComplete={toggleComplete}
          />
        )
      )}
    </div>
  );
};



export default TodoWrapper`
```

i tried to call the `addTodo` function from the loop inside `useEffect` and tried a for loop outside useEffect didn't work either as useEffect execute after the code render so at first there is no data

Comment: Could you fix the formatting here? I would like to give you a better answer, but at a glance you could look into react's [useState()](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook for managing your variable `x`; `x` should be a state instead of a var, since it is modified within another hook (your useEffect).